Salesforce SDK is sending events even with the analytics disabled
We are using 'MarketingCloudSDK' version '8.1.5' in our Android app, and we realized that even after disabling the analytics, the logs indicate that Salesforce is still sending events.
We are initializing the SDK following this way: link with analytics disabled by default.
Later on, depending on the user's consent to follow the GDPR, we enable or disable the analytics using this method: link
However, even with analytics disabled, the app logs show that Salesforce continues to send events such as:
(IdentityUpdate) event logged with attributes {platform=Android, registrationId=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX, moduleIdentities={"push":{"profileId":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","applicationId":"████████-████-████-████-████████████","installationId":"XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX","customProperties":{"deviceId":"XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX","attributes":{"UserCountry":"XX","UserLanguage":"XX","InAppMessagesEnabled":"True"},"tags":["ALL","Android","DEBUG"]}}}}

Is there a way to prevent Salesforce from sending any events if the user has disabled all consents in the app?
Edit:
After contacting our legal department, we still have some questions about the transferred data that we need to clarify with you:

Does this event contain any personal data that can identify a user, such as the profileID, deviceID, registrationID mentioned?
Additionally, is the IP address of the device transferred to Salesforce during the communication with this event?

According to the requirements of the GDPR, if the user has disabled all tracking, we expect there to be no communication of personal data between the apps and the SDKs.

The event you've identified is not an 'analytic'. It is an identity update which means something related to the contact/device was updated. It could be the contact key, an attribute, the application version, a timezone change, enabling/disabling of a feature like push or geofence messaging etc. This information is sent as part of device/contact registration, not analytics.

Hi Bill, I edited the original question with more points to clarify. Can you take a look at them, please? Thanks a lot

Work through your Account Executive.
